# What is wrong with my randrange function? An attribute error has appeared

Tags: python, random

My randrange function is giving a weird error.
Here's the code:

```
import random
ans=0
while ans!='N' or ans!='n':
           random=random.randrange(0,10);
chances=0

guess=int(input("Enter your guess: "))

while random!=guess and chances!=2:
        chances+=1
        guess = int(input("Try again: "))
        if chances == 2:
            print("Game over!! The number is " + str(random))
if random == guess:
    print("You won!!")
ans=input("Do you want to complete? N for no and Y for yes")
```

And here's the error:
`random=random.randrange(0,10); AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'randrange'`

I tried changing the function to randint but the same error appears just the 'randrange' part changes to 'randint' I am a beginner. Please help

Answer (score 3):

You redefine `random` with

```
random=random.randrange(0,10);
```

Python can't tell the difference between the module `random` you imported and the variable `random` you set after you import `random`.

To fix this, use a different name for your random integer. For example:

```
random_int = random.randrange(0, 10)
```

Remember to use the new `random_int` variable for the rest of your code.

Answer (score 0):

```
import random

ans = input()
if ans != 'N' or ans != 'n':
    r = random.randrange(0, 10);
else:
    print("Game over!!")
chances = 0

guess = int(input("Enter your guess: "))

while r != guess and chances != 2:
    chances += 1
    guess = int(input("Try again: "))
    if chances == 2:
        print("Game over!! The number is " + str(random))
if random == guess:
    print("You won!!")
ans = input("Do you want to complete? N for no and Y for yes")
```

1. the var name should not be same as import module
2. while scope never end.